# Rotate image with opencv GPU

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, gpu

I'm using [gpu::rotate](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html#gpu-rotate) from opencv lib to rotate clockwize an image.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat im_in = cv::imread( "test.png" );

    //upload image to GPU
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpu_im ;

    gpu_im.upload( im_in ); // RAM => GPU

    //Rotate from 90
    cv::Size size = im_in.size();
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpu_im_rot ;
    cv::gpu::rotate( gpu_im, gpu_im_rot, cv::Size( size.height, size.width ), -90, size.height-1, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR  );

    gpu_im_rot.download(im_in); //GPU => RAM

    cv::imwrite( "out.png", im_in );

}
```

Input Image

[image]

Output Image

[image]

I have always black line, I have tested multiple shift coordinate, and interpolation method.

I cannot find real cuda corresponding code in opencv source opencv\modules\gpu\src\imgproc.cpp

Comment: Why is your y-shift this: size.height-1, try just size.height.

Comment: Are you sure the black line is because of rotate?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in your version of opencv. It is working fine with opencv 3.2.0.

Comment: If I'm use size.height I have horizotal and vertical black line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opencv-3.4 built with cuda-10.0 and the following code works fine on my ubuntu-16.04 system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaobjdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::cuda;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat im_in = cv::imread( "test.png" );

    //upload image to GPU
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_im ;

    gpu_im.upload( im_in ); // RAM => GPU

    //Rotate from 90
    cv::Size size = im_in.size();
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_im_rot ;
    cv::cuda::rotate( gpu_im, gpu_im_rot, cv::Size( size.height, size.width ), -90, size.height-1, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR  );

    gpu_im_rot.download(im_in); //GPU => RAM

    cv::imwrite( "out.png", im_in );

}
```

Comment: I have test on nvidia jetson nano with opencv-4.1.1 (Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.166) but size.height-1 is mandatory.

Comment: This does not work for me. It displays a black image when I try it. Has anyone else tried this solution?