# Use opencv in python with gpu support to rotate images

Tags: python, opencv, gpu

I have compiled opencv 4.6.0 from source files with the cuda support. I have followed the [guide](https://thinkinfi.com/install-opencv-gpu-with-cuda-for-windows-10/) for windows 10

The process is completed and I can see my gpu. I want to rotate an image by using GPU. In other words I have this simple code

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("cat.3.jpg")
a = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
cv2.imshow("cat", a)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It works fine, but on CPU. I want a similar code in Python that runs on GPU. A similar solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731882/rotate-image-with-opencv-gpu)
for C++.

Comment: Probably your main use case is not just rotating. you for sure need to do other things with GPU, but just for this case, rotating 90 deg is just a matrix transpose operation which NumPy does much more efficiently than passing the memory to GPU's VRAM and doing the operation there and getting the result back.

Comment: This is just part of the code. I am implementing a custom data augmentation for a database of image that I need to preprocessing before. So I need to do via GPU.

Comment: learn how OpenCV uses GPUs (research your question, as explained in [ask]). one way involves `UMat`, another involves APIs that specifically use CUDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. This is the code that I have developed

```
import cv2
import cv2.cuda as cuda
image = cv2.imread("myimage.jpg")

# Storing the image on GPU
src = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
src.upload(image)

# Applying the rotation
a = cv2.cuda.rotate(src=src, dsize = (414,500), angle = 12, xShift= 0, yShift=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

# Downloading the image from GPU and visualizing the image
result = a.download()
cv2.imshow("cat", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```